# How to Ensure Imported Numeric Data in Google Sheets Using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am pretty new to apps script with google sheets and am wondering if there is a way to change my object type of values to numeric before importing into my google sheets. I have a function that takes a csv, parses and gives me what I want. But when calling the function in google sheets the imported numeric data is not numeric and mathematical sheets functions won't work. I know I can do an array formula in sheets and work that way, but is there a way to directly import the data into sheets as numbers? Sheet pictured below, code as well.

[Sheet Ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ1Gi.png)

I have worked around using =arrayformula(cell+0) to essentially copy all of the data in the imported table and work with it then, but am thinking there has to be a more efficient way such as importing it directly as numeric.

```
function ImportPlayerMPLog(playerID) {
 // Get the Link to the CSV file for player with Player ID Number
 let link = 'https://www.moneypuck.com/moneypuck/playerData/careers/gameByGame/regular/skaters/'
 link += playerID
 link += '.csv'
  // Download the CSV


 var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link)
 var csvraw = res.getContentText()
 var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(csvraw)
 // Want only columns 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,32,33,34,35,36,37,49,52,53,54,86
 var DesiredCols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,49,52,53,54,86];


 var Columns = function ExtractCols(arr,indexArr) {
   return arr.map(obj => {
     return obj.filter((ob,index) => {
       if (indexArr.includes(index)) {return ob}
     })
   })
 }


 csv = Columns(csv,DesiredCols)




 var FilterLogic = function(item){
   if(item[1]>2021 && item[9] == 'all'){
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
 var NewCSV = csv.filter(FilterLogic)
 return NewCSV
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to post and [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Sorry! @Cooper should be good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
return NewCSV
```

#### To:

```
return NewCSV.map(r => r.map(c => !isNaN(c) ? Number(c) : c));
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! What does this mean in psuedo code? Is it changing each individual index to Number(c) if it is Nan and keeping it as c if it is not NaN? Does this mean all of my "numerical values" previously were Nan?

Comment: @smileysquirrel837 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the modified script, in the case of `isNaN(c)`, when `c` is the number, false is returned. Using this, when `c` is false, `Number(c)` is returned. And, when `c` is true, `c` is returned. This document might be useful for understanding this. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)